# c program - error: variable set but not used

Tags: c

I keep getting the error `error: variable 'addresspic' set but not used` in the code below but I clearly use it.

Could somebody tell me if I am doing something wrong please?

I know that I should really be creating a pointer for `addresspic` instead of casting the return value of `get_pic()` but for now I can't understand why it is saying that the variable is not used.

```
//Function declaration
uint8_t* get_pic(int *piclen)

main() {

uint8_t addresspic;
unsigned int value;

addresspic = (uint8_t)get_pic((int*)& value);
}
```

Comment: you don't actually use the variable; you only assign it a value. Exactly as the error message says...

Comment: Also how do you compile the program?

Comment: How do your compile and wich compiler do you use ?  Normally this should be just a warning.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but casting the return value of `get_pic` to `uint8_t` is fishy. You probably want `uint8_t *addresspic; ... addresspic = get_pic((int*)& value);`.

Comment: With Codelite is a hard warning, and you can't compile it

Answer (score 1):

I guess the message isn't the most clear, but what it's telling you is that nothing reads the value form addresspic; so you assign to it (value set) but nothing depends on the value you set it to (not used).